# The wait operation timed out on Azure Server

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, model-view-controller, sql-server-2014

I am using mvc.net application and to fetch the data i am using a stored procedure. The stored procedure is working fine on local machine as well on ftp server but when i am using this stored procedure on azure server it gives the error like "The wait operation timed out". So my question is shoud i optimize my queries in stored procedure. Before using store procedure i was using LINQ query but it was taking too long to execute So make it faster i started using stored procedure but it also gives wait operation timed out error. So now what should i do.

here is my stored proceduer

```
CREATE Proc USP_GetUserDetailByID 1 
@id int
As
Begin
Select distinct
uinfo.ID ID,
uinfo.UniqueUserID UniqueUserID,
uinfo.ID UserInfoID,
uinfo.ReferredID ReferredID,
uinfo.UserTypeID UserTypeID,
uinfo.GroomBrideName GroomBrideName,
uinfo.EmailID EmailID,
uinfo.[Password] [Password], 
uinfo.ProfileCreatedFor ProfileCreatedFor,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.ProfileCreatedFor) ProfileCreatedText,
uinfo.DateOfBirth DateOfBirth,
uinfo.Gender Gender,
uinfo.Age Age,
uinfo.Height Height,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.Height) HeightText,
(Select ID from MasterDetails where ID =  uinfo.MaritalStatus) MaritalStatus,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.MaritalStatus) MaritalStatusText,
uinfo.City City,
(Select ID from MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.[State]) [State],
CASE WHEN uinfo.City is null THEN '' ELSE (SELECT DetailData FROM MasterDetails WHERE ID = uinfo.City) END as CityText,
CASE WHEN uinfo.[State] is null THEN '' ELSE (SELECT DetailData FROM MasterDetails WHERE ID = uinfo.[State]) END as StateText,
uinfo.Country Country,
(Select MasterCategoryID from MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.Country) CountryId,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = uinfo.Country) CountryText,
uinfo.Phone Phone,
uinfo.Mobile Mobile,
uinfo.RegisteredMobileNumber RegisteredMobileNumber,
uinfo.About About,
uinfo.[Status] [Status],
rel.Religion Religion,
rel.MotherTongue MotherTongue,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = rel.MotherTongue) MotherTongueText,
rel.Section Section,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = rel.Section) SectionText,
rel.Division Division,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = rel.Division) DivisonText,
edu.EducationLevel EducationalLevel,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.EducationLevel) EducationalLevelText,
edu.EducationFeild EducationalField,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.EducationFeild) EducationalFeildText,
edu.GraduationDegree GraduationDegree,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.GraduationDegree) GraduationDegreeText,
edu.MasterDegree MasterDegree,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.MasterDegree) MasterDegreeText,
edu.WorkWith WorkWith,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.WorkWith) WOrkingWithText,
edu.WorkingGroup WorkingGroup,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.WorkingGroup) WorkingGroupText,
edu.WorkingAs WorkingAs,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.WorkingAs) WorkingAsText,
edu.AnnualIncome AnnualIncome,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = edu.AnnualIncome) AnnualIncomeText,
edu.InterestedInSettlingAbroad InsertedInSettingAbroad,
hob.Hobbies Hobbies,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = hob.Hobbies) HobbiesText,
hob.DressStyle,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = hob.DressStyle) DressStyleText,
hob.SportsFitness SportsFitness,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = hob.SportsFitness) SportsFitnessText,
hob.FavouriteCuisine FavouriteCuisine,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = hob.FavouriteCuisine) FavouriteCuisineText,
hob.FavouriteVacationDestination FavouriteVacationDestination,
hob.FavouriteMusic FavouriteMusic,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = hob.FavouriteMusic) FavouriteMusicText,
hob.FavouriteBooks FavouriteBooks,
hob.PreferredMovies PreferredMovies,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = hob.PreferredMovies) PreferredMoviesText,
life.Diet Diet,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = life.Diet) DietText,
life.Smoke Smoke,
life.Drink Drink,
life.SkinTone Complexion,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = life.SkinTone) ComplexionText,
life.BodyType BodyType,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = life.BodyType) BodyTypeText,
life.BloodGroup BloodGroup,
life.[Weight] [Weight],
life.ResidentialStatus ResidentialStatus,
life.OwnHouse OwnHouse,
life.OwnCar OwnCar,
life.LanguageKnown LanguageKnown,
fd.FamilyValue FamilyValue,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = fd.FamilyValue) FamilyValueText,
fd.FamilyType FamilyType,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = fd.FamilyType) FamilyTypeText,
fd.FamilyStatus FamilyStatus,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = fd.FamilyStatus) FamilyStatusText,
fd.Father Father,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = fd.Father) FatherText,
fd.Mother Mother,
(Select DetailData from  MasterDetails where ID = fd.Mother) MotherText,
fd.Brothers Brothers,
fd.MarriedBrothers MarriedBrothers,
fd.Sisters Sisters,
fd.MarriedSisters MarriedSisters,
fd.LivingWithParents LivingWithParents,
rel.ReligiousValues ReligiousValues,
uinfo.HightLightUserAbout HightLightUserAbout,
uinfo.FbUserDetail FbUserDetail

from UsersInfo uinfo 
left join EducationAndOccupation edu on uinfo.ID = edu.UserID 
    left join ReligionAndEthinicity rel on uinfo.ID = rel.UserID
left join HobbiesAndInterests hob on uinfo.ID = hob.UserID
left join LifestyleAndAttributes life on uinfo.ID = life.UserID
    left join FamilyDetails fd on uinfo.ID = fd.UserID
where uinfo.ID = @id
order by uinfo.ID desc
```

End

Comment: Simply encapsulating the parameterized query in a proc won't inherently improve performance, although stored procedures do have other benefits. [Upload your actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question if you need help with query/index tuning. Also, add `CREATE TABLE` DDL to your question, including indexes and constraints. I wouldn't expect this query to take more than a second with proper indexes.

Comment: Here is link . https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkQ93ryaf

Comment: i'd uploaded the execution plan

Comment: @DanGuzman here is the link of one drive for execution plan https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=972565A0F90BDB6D&id=972565A0F90BDB6D%21105&parId=972565A0F90BDB6D%21104&o=OneUp